# Getting error "state" is undefined in stateprovider and reducer using context API react, here is my code

Tags: reactjs, reducers, react-context, session-state-provider

index.js file- where I have passed initial state and reducer

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

import reducer, { initialState } from './components/reducer';
import { StateProvider } from './components/StateProvider';


ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <React.StrictMode>

    <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
   
    <App />

    </StateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I'm getting error of state undefined, though state has initial value in reducer, and state provider is combined with reducer in index.js but still state is not getting initialized. Any help would be appreciated
...........................................................................

```js
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Feed from './components/Feed';
import MessageSender from './components/MessageSender';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
import SidebarRow from './components/SidebarRow';
import Story from './components/Story';
import StoryReel from './components/StoryReel';
import Widget from './components/Widget';
import Login from './components/Login';
import { useStateValue } from './components/StateProvider';
import {useState} from 'react';
 

function App() {


  const [state, setUser] = useStateValue()
     

  return (

    <div className="app"> 
  {!state.user ? (
         <Login/>

       ):(
       <>
       
       <Header/>
       
       <div className="app__body">
       <SidebarRow/>
       <Sidebar/>
       <Feed/>
       <Widget/>
       </div>
       
          </>      
      )}
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Login page.js
.........................................................................................

```js
import React from 'react';
import "./Login.css";
// import Button from '@material'

import {firebase} from './GoogleAuth-fbase';
import { actionTypes } from "./reducer"; 
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';


function Login(){

    const {state, dispatch} = useStateValue(); 

    const signIn = () =>
    {

        var google_provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(google_provider)
        .then((result) => {

            dispatch({
                type: actionTypes.SET_USER,
                user: result.user,
            })

            // console.log(result);
        })
        .catch((err) => {console.log(err)});
    };

    return(
        <div className="login">

        <div className="login__logo">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6f/35/0d/6f350d177d15776f7874b5c4d0e68a5b.jpg" alt="logo"/>
        <img src="https://uspto.report/TM/86693240/mark" alt="logo"/>
        </div>
    <button type="submit" onClick={signIn}>
    Sign In
    </button>

        
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

**

Reducer.js
......................................................................................

```js
export const initialState = {
    user: null,
};

export const actionTypes = {
    SET_USER: "SET_USER",
};

function reducer(state, action){
console.log(action);
switch(action.type){
    case actionTypes.SET_USER:
        return {
            ...state,
            user:action.user,
        };

        default: 
            return state;
}
};

export default reducer;
```

state provider
...................................................................

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer} from 'react';


export const StateContext = createContext();


export const StateProvider = ({reducer, initialState, children}) => (

    <StateContext.Provider value = {useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider> 

);

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Comment: I tried using both {state, dispatch} and [state, dispatch] in both Login.js and app.js

Comment: Where is the state provider? U didnt use it, so context consumers values will be undefined. See the API.

Comment: I Have used stateprovider to wrap entire App.js in index,js file, but if your telling something else I'm sorry can you please elaborate

Comment: and state provider is mentioned in last snippet, you can see that I guess

Comment: So show index.js, can you reproduce it in codesandbox?

Comment: Sorry I don't know codes and box, this is my first question in stackoverflow so don't mind, but I'll udpate that code of index.js here

Comment: You can just edit the question. And as you see you only pass the initial state to the provider where its null.

Comment: I Have updated the index.js file in question, so there is initial value right for initial state and reducer but I'm getting undefined for state, I had copied this code from YouTube video, same code was working fine in that video, I checked each line but its not working in my project.